# Paging disappears after filtering in SPGridView

Tags: spgridview

I am using an `SPGridView` in which I have put paging and filtering facility. But whenever I change the page and then do filtering, the paging disappears.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to again specify pagination in page index change event.

**Example**

```
public void gdSharedReport_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
     gdSharedReport.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
     gdSharedReport.AllowPaging = true;
     gdSharedReport.PageIndexChanging += new GridViewPageEventHandler(gdSharedReport_PageIndexChanging);
     gdSharedReport.PagerTemplate = null;
     gdSharedReport.DataSource = DataTable;
     gdSharedReport.DataBind();
}
```